# ARM - C - arm-none-eabi-ld : not finding vsprintf,strcpy

Tags: c, cross-compiling, ld

On Ubuntu I **cross-compile** a code for the raspberry pi

but when I try to **link** objects that **use standard c libraries** I just added

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -g vectors.o notmain.o bm_bcm2835.o uart.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
```

it complains about not finding standard functions

```
uart.c:135: undefined reference to `strcpy'
uart.c:142: undefined reference to `vsprintf'
```

so far I tried, adding **-lc -lgcc** but the linker complains it cannot find them either

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lc
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lgcc
```

I tried adding these flags to the compiler, it compiles fine, but the linker throws the same error

any idea what's going wrong ?

here is the makefile:

```
ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -g
LDOPS = -g

all : kernel.img

clean :
rm -f *.o
rm -f *.bin
rm -f *.hex
rm -f *.srec
rm -f *.elf
rm -f *.list
rm -f *.img

vectors.o : vectors.s
$(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) vectors.s -o vectors.o

uart.o : uart.c
$(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -c uart.c -o uart.o -lc -lgcc

notmain.o : notmain.c
$(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -c notmain.c -o notmain.o

notmain.elf : memmap vectors.o notmain.o uart.o
$(ARMGNU)-ld $(LDOPS) vectors.o notmain.o uart.o -T memmap -o notmain.elf
$(ARMGNU)-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list

kernel.img : notmain.elf
$(ARMGNU)-objcopy --srec-forceS3 notmain.elf -O srec notmain.srec
$(ARMGNU)-objcopy notmain.elf -O binary kernel.img
```

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: its just an apt-get install..I added the makefile

Comment: The "*-nostdlib*" and "*use standard c libraries*" are not adding up.

Comment: tried without it, same problem

Comment: `-freestanding` might be a problem too.

Comment: yep, now theres only that vpsprintf missing reference

Comment: But eventually it won't solve your problems. Since it is a bare-metal program, you need these switches, so need some kind of library implementing a subset of standard function. Take a look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223929/c-standard-libraries-on-bare-metal

Comment: ah damned, I knew it all along, I'd have to implement sub functions that deal with memory and stuffs...

Comment: on the makefile, regarding each 'recipe'.  Every line, past the first line of a recipe must be indented via a <tab>.   Also what is this line: `ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi`  That '?' is very suspect.  Also, to avoid the `make' utility having to re-evaluate each macro each time that macro is invoked, suggest replacing the '=' with ':='

Comment: regarding: `$(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -c uart.c -o uart.o -lc -lgcc`  Do not place library names on a compile statement.  Library names are needed on `link` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's bare metal, there is no sub structure for standards c functions

so here is an example of how to implement bare metal subsystem (heap and such) with newlib

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=280209&p=1697302#p1697302

Answer (score 1):

If you build with `-nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding`, you are telling the compiler (driver) that you do not want to build for a standard C environment. As a result, standard C functions such as `vfprintf` and `strcpy` are not available and cannot be used.

Comment: it's a bare metal program, so maybe the make file is that way for a reason, I'll try remove them